# How to grant permissions for Modal dialog popup in sheet contained in G Suite

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, modal-dialog, shared, google-workspace

I created a sheet in my personal drive with scripts that used a modal dialog popup.  Everything worked great.  Granted permissions.  I move the sheet into a new G suite shared drive.  Regranted permissions to myself.  Now, everyone that logs in with the G Suite account can do everything and it works.  Using my outside account (the sheet is shared outside the G Suite), I can do almost everything, but I get

Execution failed: You do not have permission to call showModalDialog

With my outside account from the G Suite, am I now no longer allowed or able or can even grant that permission?  Is there something else somewhere I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: There is something else you need to do and that is to share the script.

Comment: Does this `outside account` have access to the script? How are you trying to run the script? Is it manually, or through a trigger?

Comment: It sounds to me like you may be trying to access the spreadsheet from the outside account with Spreadsheet.openById() and in that case the UI is not available.  Just guessing.  I need to be able to see the code. NCNH

Comment: All good thoughts. Thanks for taking the time to help.

The sheet, the script, any openById doc are all shared with the outside account.  All other scripts functions fine....those from buttons, custom menu and onEdit/onOpen and the other 50 functions.  No problem.  The html trying to be presented is being generated off a row of information stored on a sheet.  I even use a custom menu driven function just to show a popup in order to trigger the permissions for first time use.  All working.

Comment: In addition, I have a separate approach to this same function that uses a custom button that actually does gather docbyid, and that works fine.  This function is triggered by a custom onEdit, and all other custom onEdit functions are working....except the onEdit triggering popup.

Comment: Wish I could share all the code, but it is more than a few lines.  Here is the skinny:

-Custom Trigger on Edit calls a function onSpecialEdit
-this calls a function  with showModalDialog.
-EVERY other function works fine in whole 2,300 lines of scripts.
-Clicking a button or a menu item, showModalDialog is fine and no problems
-Even those in the G Suite domain have the same error
-I've gone into security for G Suite and selected the script as a "safe" script to allow
-When I try to share the script, I get "An error occurred. The selected files cannot be shared at this time."

Comment: -Every other script works fine for all users. showmodal is no problem from menu or custom buttons.  Even email is sent directly from the sheet without permission problem.  Only the script that comes through onSpecialEdit and only the script showing modal dialog....for everyone

Comment: Could you share a minimized example of the code you're using, that will reproduce this behaviour? Also, I'd suggest you to edit your question, including the information you provided in the comments, in an organized and easy to understand way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone else has a better answer, I believe that the permissions for the UI to come from an onEdit (or even a triggered onSpecialEdit) will not allow a modalshowdialog....except for the person to created the onSpecialEdit trigger based on onEdit.

Since onEdit are less intentional for the user, the types of functions that send emails or popUp on the screen with information is not allowed, except the one single person who created the script trigger.

To get around this, I needed to create and insert a graphic image to be a button.  Assigned a script to the button.  The script pulled a value off a hidden cell to determine which cell the action should be taken on (a column of data validation check boxes that I originally wanted to trigger), and then pass that value to the script with the UI.

That works, but just not as clean and simple as checking a box and seeing the results.